# os.path.isfile(file_path) return false when file_path is a relative path, why?

Tags: python

I want to search keyword in all file under my directory 'excercise' which contains several subdirectories, such as '20150516'.

Here is my code: ()

```
import os,sys,view_all

def search_special(file):
    with open(file,'r') as fp:
        while 1:
            line = fp.readline()
            if len(line) == 0:
                break
            if 'KeyboardInterrupt' in line:
                res.append(file)
                break
    if not (file in res):
        print "%s has no keyword 'KeyboardInterrupt'"%file

def traver_path(main_dir):
    for path_name in os.listdir(main_dir):
        current_dir = os.path.abspath(main_dir)
        recursive_dir = os.path.join(current_dir,path_name)
        if os.path.isdir(recursive_dir):
            traver_path(recursive_dir)
        if os.path.isfile(recursive_dir):
            if path_name[-3:] == '.py':
                search_special(recursive_dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = []
    traver_path('.')
    # print res
    for item in res:
        view_all.print_file(item)
```

And it works well. But if I do a little change to func traver_path like:

```
def traver_path(main_dir):
    for path_name in os.listdir(main_dir):
        if os.path.isdir(path_name):
            traver_path(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(main_dir),path_name))
        if os.path.isfile(path_name):
            if path_name[-3:] == '.py':
                search_special(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(main_dir),path_name))
```

Notice that arguments for os.path.isdir and os.path.isfile have been changed.(No longer an abspath)

And I found something interesting when i debug it by pdb.

```
(Pdb)
> /Users/Crayon_277/Develop/Project/Python/exercise/view_special.py(27)traver_path()
-> if os.path.isdir(path_name):
(Pdb) p path_name
'20150507'
(Pdb) n
> /Users/Crayon_277/Develop/Project/Python/exercise/view_special.py(28)traver_path()
-> traver_path(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(main_dir),path_name))
```

## Get into the subdirectory 20150507

```
(Pdb) p path_name
'common_divisor.py'
(Pdb) n
> /Users/Crayon_277/Develop/Project/Python/exercise/view_special.py(29)traver_path()
-> if os.path.isfile(path_name):
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(26)isfile()
-> def isfile(path):
(Pdb) return
--Return--
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(31)isfile()->False
-> return False
```

Return False, which should be True, cause common_divisor.py **is** a file.

Another test:

```
>>> for i in os.listdir('.'):
...     print i,str(os.path.isfile(i))
...
.DS_Store True
.view_all.py.swp True
.view_special.py.swp True
20150506 False
20150507 False
20150509 False
20150510 False
20150511 False
20150512 False
20150513 False
20150514 False
20150516 False
view_all.py True
view_all.pyc True
view_special.py True
>>> for i in os.listdir('./20150509'):
...     print i,str(os.path.isfile(i))
...
bibao.py False
chinese_test.py False
decorate.py False
encrypt.py False
isinstance_test.py False
python3_test.py False
```

Am I come to the right conclusion that os.path.isfile better works with an abspath than relative path?

## And WHY?

Comment: Did you know that all of this could be avoided by simply using [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)?

Comment: @MattDMo No. But is grep a shell command? Could you be more specific?

Comment: you could also use `os.walk()`

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided? `grep` is a utility available on most Unix and Linux platforms, including OS X (which I assume you're using based on your path names). The link gives all the details on how to use it, or you can type `man grep` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my research, the key is the directory where you start your program.

Let's pdb the isfile function

```
(Pdb)
> /Users/Crayon_277/Develop/Project/Python/exercise/view_special.py(29)traver_path()
-> if os.path.isfile(path_name):
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(26)isfile()
-> def isfile(path):
(Pdb)
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(28)isfile()
-> try:
(Pdb)
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(29)isfile()
-> st = os.stat(path)
(Pdb)
OSError: (2, 'No such file or directory', 'common_divisor.py') 
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(29)isfile()
-> st = os.stat(path)
(Pdb)
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(30)isfile()
-> except os.error:
(Pdb)
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py(31)isfile()
-> return False
```

Ok, now we know specific error,"No such file or directory".
But `traver_path(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(main_dir),path_name))`, I did pass the full path into recursive function traver_path. So That's the point. I started the program in the "root" directory, where the isfile func based on.

```
os.path.isfile(path_name)
```

If path_name wasn't an abspath, python thought it would be under "root" directory, cause it's just a str like "common_divisor.py", even though I set the argument to the recursive function.

Another option: using os.walk like this

```
def traver_dir(main_dir):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(main_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file[-3:] == '.py':
                search_special(root+'/'+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use `os.walk()` for your specific needs.  Also, note when you are trying to do os.listdir('some_directory') - what you get is a list of names. The reason `os.path.isfile(x)` is False is - those names are *not* files in current directory. Hence you get it True when you do it for `os.listdir('.')` (current_directory) but not when you do `os.listdir('./20150509')` . A bash equivalent of it would be `ls ./20150509` and then say `ls bibao.py`, obviously second is going to show 'No such file or directory'. You might want to first try `os.path.exists` that might help and avoid confusion.